# Formally proving Unitary Matrices as Product of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am asked to prove that any unitary matrix can be written as the product of 
$$\begin{bmatrix}\exp(i\phi)&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&\exp(i\phi)\end{bmatrix},\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

I can see it because these are just rotations, so the property of unitary would still remain.  I am just unsure how to prove ANY U can be written this way

Comment: Little bit of nitpicking here, but you want to show you can generate any 2x2 unitary matrix as product of those matrices, not any unitary matrix. 

"I can see it because these are just rotations, so the property of unitary would still remain." As a matter of fact, the product of any two unitary matrices $A$ and $B$ is again unitary, since $AB(AB)^* = A(BB^*)A^* = AA^* = I$. It is then easy to check that $n \times n $ unitary matrices form a group, so you want to show that these three elements are generators for the whole group.

Comment: Is it enough to show they are orthogonal matrices?  And that I only need 3, because the off diagonal elements must be st b=-c

Comment: Could you maybe explain why you would think that showing that they are orthogonal would help you? I made a small in my previous post by the way, instead of 'generators', it should be 'generating set of $U(2)$'.

Comment: Looking further at your problem, I'm pretty sure that it is actually *not* possible to write any matrix in $U(2)$ as a product of these three matrices. It is easy to see what the effect of the first two matrices have on each other, and also on the the third one: adding phase factors to each element. This doesn't seem to be enough to generate any matrix in $U(2)$.

Comment: I really don't know if it can.  This is for a QM course, and Ive never taken group theory, so my thought was that because the rank of U(2) is 3, if we have 3 orthogonal matrices, we could express every u in U(2) as the product, kind of as if we could span R^3 with 3 linearly independent vectors

Comment: The concept of linear independence only works if you're taking linear combinations of your vectors (and in this case your vectors are matrices!), not products. Are you using a book for your QM course? If so, which one? I'll have a look at it tomorrow if I have the time

Comment: We are using Quantum Processes, Computation and Information by Schumacher.  It doesn't dive in at all, to this group stuff

Answer (score 0):

Another generator. $U(2)$ depends on $4$ real parameters; more precisely $U(2)=\{\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta)e^{ia}&-\sin(\theta)e^{i(a+h)}\\\sin(\theta)e^{ib}&\cos(\theta)e^{i(b+h)}\end{pmatrix};\theta,a,b,h\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Proposition. A generator is $G=\{diag(e^{ia},1),diag(1,e^{ib}),Rot(\theta)=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta)&-\sin(\theta)\\\sin(\theta)&\cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix};a,b,\theta\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

Proof. $diag(e^{i(a-b)},1)Rot(\theta)diag(e^{ib},1)diag(1,e^{i(h+b)})=\begin{pmatrix}\cos(\theta)e^{ia}&-\sin(\theta)e^{i(a+h)}\\\sin(\theta)e^{ib}&\cos(\theta)e^{i(b+h)}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: SO would $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\1&1\end{bmatrix}$ generate instead of Rot, which just limits theta to 45 degrees

Comment: As Kenneth , I think that the diagonal matrices and $Rot(\pi/4)$ do not suffice to generate $U(2)$.